# Why is my camera (that follows the player) not working (SpriteKit)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So, in this game I'm making the player can move left and right using the accelerometer and jump by tapping the screen. Now the player must evade enemies frome the sky and climb up by jumping on de fallen enemies. The player should be able to go up infinitely until he dies, therefore a camera is needed to follow the player on his journey up. I have read some other Stack Overflow posts and consulted Apple's programming guide, but I'm not able to figure it out. This is what I added:

```
-(void) createSceneContents
{
    self.world = [SKNode node];
    self.playerSize = self.frame.size.width/7;
    self.player = [self.playerData newPlayer:self.playerSize];
    self.player.name = @"player";
    self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.playerSize-5,self.playerSize-5)];
    self.player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = self.playerCategory;
    self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = self.enemyCategory | self.edgeCategory;
    self.isTouchingGround = NO;
    self.player.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 100);
    [self.playerData movementSetup];
    [self addChild:self.world];
    [self.world addChild:self.player];
}
```

There are more things in this method, but those aren't important for this question.

```
-(void) didSimulatePhysics
{
        self.world.position = CGPointMake(-(self.player.position.x-(self.size.width/2)), -(self.player.position.y-(self.size.height/2)));
}
```

Then there are a lot of other methods adding other things to the game including enemies, collision handeling etc.

Ok, so when I did this the player movement suddenly stopped working, the players spawn position was changed and the rest of the sprites, that weren't child nodes of world, just kept on going.

Why isn't this working, how can I fix it, and how does it work?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851265/moving-a-camera-in-spritekit/23856474#23856474

Comment: I don't think you could've find more poorly phrased and misleading title as the one you've set to your question...

Comment: What's so misleading about the title

Comment: Your asking about the view being centred at the player's position. But from first look at the question title, it looks like you are trying to implement the camera, i.e. taking pictures, into your sprite-kit game. Could be just me though.....Anyway, I'm still haven't finished going thru your post, and sangony link. Will be back with you in couple of minutes mate...

Comment: What I meant was an ingame camera through which you observe everything. It would be able to move around the world revealing content that isn't visible from its initial position. The camera movement should be triggered by the player moving

Comment: You are wanting the player to always remain at the centre of the screen?

Comment: BTW- what method are you using to make the player jump when tapping the screen?

Comment: Also, are you having some sort of jump animation when the player is jumping? could be that the movement haven't stopped working, but since the player is now centred in the middle of the view, it just looks like it stopped jumping. Also take in mind, that world's coordinate system, and your scene coordinate system, aren't necessarily the same...

Comment: Yes I think some things are sort of contradicting each other, I'm gonna rewrite that class I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a camera follow your player add these simple lines of code:

```
    int cameraEdge = 100;

    if (self.player.position.y > cameraEdge) {
    worldPosition.y = cameraEdge - self.player.position.y;

    }
    self.world.position = worldPosition;
```

What this does: Whenever your player's y-position is higher than 100 (or whatever you set it to) the world's position starts following the player. I've tested it and it works perfectly